# Remove substring from string in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to remove all the words `not` from the Dataframe below.

```
d = {'keep': ["not useful", "useful", "not useful", "useful", "useful"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['keep'] = df['keep'].replace('not', '', inplace=True)
df
```

This results in my 'keep' column being equal to `None`.
Not sure what I'm doing incorrectly here.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues:

1. `inplace=True` performs **inplace** operation, so it modifies the series directly and returns `None`.
2. `df['keep'].replace(a,b)` replaces for the **whole** strings, not substrings.

You want:

```
df['keep'] = df['keep'].replace('not','', regex=True)
```

Comment: This works, thank you. Will accept in 10'

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
for i in range(len(df['keep'])):
    df['keep'][i] = df['keep'][i].replace('not', '')
```

Comment: Please add an explanation highlighting the important bits of your solution, or include a documentation link, or how it differs in an important way from OP's attempt, etc. Code-only answers are frowned upon on SO, are of low quality (reflecting on the platform), tend to promote *haz me the code* Q's, and have little if any long term value. Future visitors should be able to learn from your response, and apply knowledge to their own issues. Generally, simple answers like this are more appropriately left as a Comment, and are very Welcome as Comments. Quality answers are more likely to be upvoted.